# how to decompose a gamma distribution into two gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, decomposition, gamma

Is there an algorithm available in R that can decompose a gamma distribution into two (or more) gamma distributions? If so, can you give me an example with it? Basically, I have a data set that looks like a gamma distribution if I plot it with respect to time (it's a time series data). Basically, this data contains the movement of the animal. And the animal can be in two different states: hungry, not hungry. My immediate reaction was to use the Hidden Markov Model and see if I can predict the two states. I was trying to use the depmix() function from depmixS4 library in R to see if I can see the two different states. However, I don't really know how to use this function in gamma distribution. The following is the code that I wrote, but it says that I need an argument for gamma, which I don't understand. Can someone tell me what parameter I should use and how to determine the parameter? Thanks!

```
mod <- depmix(freq ~ 1, data = mod.data, nstates = 2, family = gamma())
fit.mod <- fit(mod)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you give more detail, and/or an example? More context might help too.

Comment: So I have a data set that looks like a gamma distribution if I plot it with respect to time (it's a time series data). Basically, this data contains the movement of the animal. And the animal can be in two different states: hungry, not hungry. My immediate reaction was to use the Hidden Markov Model and see if I can divide the two states into two gamma distributions. I was trying to use the depmix() function from depmixS4 library in R to see if I can see the two different states. However, I don't really know how to use this function in gamma distribution.